# How to remove from all files in folder the lines with specific string

Tags: linux, powershell, shell

I'm looking for the way to remove all lines from file (for all files in folder) have string # and also copy the name of file and add it as first column (or last column):

so as example I have:

```
# DX 
# DEPTH 
MD   DX  DY
100  23  35
100  23  35
```

output should be like this, let's say file name is test2:

```
test2 MD   DX  DY
test2 100  23  35
test2 100  23  35
```

thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing simple bash structures, iterate through each line of each file, save the line and file name as variables, then per line in file, print both variables together.

```
for file in *; do
  for (( i = 1 ; i <= $( grep "" -c $file ) ; i++ ); do
    line=$( cat $file | head -n ${i} | tail -1 )
    echo "${file} ${line}"
  done
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering using find/sed to construct the command line for each process.

```
find * -type f | xargs -I@ sed -e '/#/d' -e 's/^/@ /' @
```

The above will print the combined output. If you need to modify the files, consider using inline edit (sed -i)

```
find * -type f | xargs -I@ sed -i -e '/#/d' -e 's/^/@ /' @
```

Comment: thanks for codes!! how could I copy the name of file and add it as first column?

Comment: The output already includes the filename (running on Mint 19) as the first column. Are you using the output only or the file update command ?